# How to fix "uninitialized constant" when using "namespace" based application

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to create a namespace-based application in Ruby with Sinatra, but I have a problem that I don't understand.

An example structure:

./api/v1/service/app_service.rb:

```
module Api::V1::Service
    class AppService
    end
end
```

./run.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require './api/v1/service/app_service'
```

and, in this case, I got an "uninitialized constant Api" error.

If I use the normal module creation, everything is OK:

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Service
      class AppService
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I tried a bad and ugly solution as well, requiring a file which predefined every module:

./predefine.rb:

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Service
    end
  end
end
```

./run.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require './predefine'
require './api/v1/service/app_service'
```

but this is not a solution because the rspec tests run to fail with the same error.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Hi there. Is anything else to go in `Api`, `V1` or `Service`? If not, I'd say the easiest way to get rid of the nesting is to get rid of the modules. 3 deep is about as far as I ever get, 4 is usually a code smell that indicates you're not writing idiomatic Ruby but something more akin to Java.